# Ajax request slows down the rest of the function, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, drag-and-drop

I made some drag and drop ability for saving images and I want to see what images I just save. 
The problem is that I won't wait while ajax request will send that image to server, I want instant preview of the image. I made code that could make this, but when I add ajax request to it, I don't see this image on my html page until ajax request is done. But, if I'll comment this ajax request, image appear instantly on html page. How can I get all of it? Ajax + instant preview.

Here is my code, feel free to ask me about it:

```
// initialise our dropzone and set ondrop event function 
var dropzone = document.getElementById('ta');

dropzone.ondrop = function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
};

// preview image that was added to dropzone
function previewImg(file) {

   var image = new Image();


   image.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(file);// make url for image using webkitURL

   image.width = 550; // a fake resize

   document.getElementById('body').appendChild(image); // add image to element (for example to the body)

}    

function readfiles(files) {
   var formData = new FormData();

   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

   previewImg(files[i]); // call for preview

   formData.append('file'+i, files[i]); // add file to form


   }
   formData.append('moreInfo','myValuableValue');// you can append additional string info

   // if we comment this request preview will appear instant
   // but if we not, preview will appear only after end of ajax request
   $.ajax({
    url: './file_handler.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('done');
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
   });


}
```

I want to fix this, but I don't know how, I use jQuery $.ajax request. By the way, console output slows too and shows all at once after request end. Show me the way please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the settings you pass to your $.ajax call, set `async: true`.